# Python Django Error: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What is the solution for following problem?

Error is on line 10!

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\farib\Desktop\Python\classProject\signup\templates\services.html, error at line 10

Could not parse the remainder: '(airquality' from '(airquality'
1   {% extends "layout.html" %}
2   {% block content %}
3       <h1 style="color:rgb(51, 48, 51)">Services</h1>
4       <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="services" class="needs-validation">
5           {% csrf_token %}
6           {{ servicesform }}
7           <input id="sendBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Analyze">
8       </form>
9       <h3>Address: {{ address }}, City: {{ city }}, Country: {{ country }}, Latitude: {{ latitude }}, Longitude: {{ longitude }}</h3>
10      {% if airquality < 50 %}
11      <h3 style="background-color: green;">Air Quality: {{ airquality }}</h3>
12      {% elif (airquality >= 51) and (airquality < 100) %}
13      <h3 style="background-color: yellow;">Air Quality: {{ airquality }}</h3>
14      {% elif (airquality >= 101) and (airquality < 150) %}
15      <h3 style="background-color: orange;">Air Quality: {{ airquality }}</h3>
16      {% elif (airquality >= 151) and (airquality < 200) %}
17      <h3 style="background-color: red;">Air Quality: {{ airquality }}</h3>
18      {% elif (airquality >= 201) and (airquality < 300) %}
19      <h3 style="background-color: purple;">Air Quality: {{ airquality }}</h3>
20      {% elif airquality >= 301 %}
```

I tried to generate different html/css code based on a variable but I failed.

Also my installed apps are:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main',
'signup'
```

]

my source code is as follows:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 style="color:rgb(51, 48, 51)">Services</h1>
    <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="services" class="needs-validation">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ servicesform }}
        <input id="sendBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Analyze">
    </form>
    <h3>Address: {{ address }}, City: {{ city }}, Country: {{ country }}, Latitude: {{ latitude }}, Longitude: {{ longitude }}</h3>

    {% if airquality < 50 %}
    <h3 style="background-color: rgb(0, 228, 0);">Air Quality Index: {{ airquality }}</h3>
    {% elif (airquality >= 51) and (airquality < 100) %}
    <h3 style="background-color: yellow;">Air Quality Index: {{ airquality }}</h3>
    {% elif (airquality >= 101) and (airquality < 150) %}
    <h3 style="background-color: rgb(255, 126, 0);">Air Quality Index: {{ airquality }}</h3>
    {% elif (airquality >= 151) and (airquality < 200) %}
    <h3 style="background-color: red;">Air Quality Index: {{ airquality }}</h3>
    {% elif (airquality >= 201) and (airquality < 300) %}
    <h3 style="background-color: rgb(143, 63, 151);">Air Quality Index: {{ airquality }}</h3>
    {% elif airquality >= 301 %}
    <h3 style="background-color: rgb(126, 0, 35 );">Air Quality Index: {{ airquality }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
```

Edit: The problem was I put parenthesis in the elif blocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templates don't allow parentheses in the if tags!
[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators)

The clue is in the last part of the error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(airquality' from '(airquality'

So the error is actually at line 12.

Comment: You are right. It fixed the error. Thank you very much.